# OpenGL Camera Orientation

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, glut, 3d-rendering

I'm  having trouble orienting the camera the way I want. I got that I need to use `gluLookAt` to set the camera. As far as I understood the first three is for the location of the camera, the second set is for destination and the third set is for the camera `upvector` and I'm trying to implement a box which the camera should be looking at its center. This box consists of 6 triangles, does not necessarily make a decent box. To get its center, I get the average of all triangle's vertices (`x`, `y`, and `z`).

So this is inside my display function :

```
 Vect v=getBoxCenter();
 gluLookAt(camera.pos.x, camera.pos.y, camera.pos.z,   
        v.x,v.y,v.z,   
        camera.upVector.x, camera.upVector.y, camera.upVector.z);    
 glColor3f(1, 0, 0);    
 glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);    
 glVertex3f(0, 0, 0); glVertex3f(100, 0, 0); glVertex3f(0, 100, 0);    
 glEnd();    
 glutSwapBuffers();
```

When I do not use `gluLookAt`, the triangle shows up just fine at the center of the screen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since this is old-school OpenGL: what does your projection matrix look like?

Comment: I have these in the main function:    
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
 glLoadIdentity();    
and what is the new school OpenGL?

Comment: Well there's your problem. you should read up on gluPerspective()

Comment: modern opengl doesn't have matrix modes or glBegin()/glEnd(), and uses shaders and vertex buffers instead. it's a completely different way of working. ("modern" as: for the past 10 years)

Comment: @Rabbid76 They already said that they use glLoadIdentity() as the projection matrix...

Comment: @Rabbid76 I just tried setting near plane 1, far plane 1000, and fov to 80. I still didn't get anything: gluPerspective(80, 1, 1, 1000);   let me try your last message, thanks.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I had these before my display function was called: glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

 glLoadIdentity();


 glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1000.0, 1000.0);
 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); and still nothing

Comment: @hebele Hi, maybe your `v` is just wrong.

Comment: @Rabbid76, thanks for all the help. `camera.upVector` is `0,1,0` and `camera.position` is `20,20,40`. `v` in my case is the center of the box that my camera is supposed to look at. Basically, I have 6 triangles forming a box. I find its center by averaging the 6 triangles' `x`,`y`, and `z` coordinates.

Comment: `gluLookAt` _multiplies_ the current matrix with some view transformation matrix. If your current matrix is not well-defined, the result will be meaningless.